spawn python ENOENT at ChildProcess... | Vercel
I've deployed a node.js backend on Vercel, which includes a Python script used to fetch user data. It worked fine on localhost, but after deployment, it gives error when trying to access the user data. The error message is -
Uncaught Exception: Error: spawn python ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn python',
  path: 'python',
  spawnargs: [ '-u', '/var/task/backend/main.py' ]
}

node.js file
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { PythonShell } = require("python-shell");
const path = require("path");

// Resolve the absolute path to main.py
const scriptPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../main.py");

router.get("/:username", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.params.username;

  let options = {
    mode: "text",
    pythonPath: "python",
    pythonOptions: ["-u"], // get print results in real-time
    scriptPath: path.dirname(scriptPath),
  };

  let pyshell = new PythonShell("main.py", options);

  pyshell.send(username + "\n"); // Send the username followed by a newline character

  let dataChunks = [];
  let errorOccurred = false;

  pyshell.on("message", function (message) {
    dataChunks.push(message);
  });

  pyshell.on("stderr", function (err) {
    console.error(`stderr: ${err}`);
    errorOccurred = true;
  });

  pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (errorOccurred) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Python script exited with error" });
    }

    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Python script exited with error" });
    }

    const completeData = dataChunks.join("");
    let parsedData;
    try {
      parsedData = JSON.parse(completeData);
    } catch (err) {
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ error: "Error parsing data from Python script" });
    }

    res.json(parsedData);
  });
});

module.exports = router;


Ran the code on localhost and it worked fine.

How do you know the Vercel environment has python at all? By the error message, it looks like it doesn't.

Here's the screenshot - https://drive.google.com/file/d/190SaQBdBy34YmQamD77TP4dh4A2ZBIzm/view?usp=sharing

That doesn't say the environment has the python command, that you'd use to run Python files.

Then, how to make it work?

You might want to ask Vercel customer support that.
